# How to iterate over a list that has multiple sets of items in jsp

Tags: list, jsp, jstl

I have a list as following

dnsList has

urls(url1,url2,url3 and so on) and their corresponding values of dns_time,update_time,status_code.
connList has
urls(url1,url2,url3 and so on) and their corresponding values of connection_time,update_time.

My servlet returns the dnsList,connList to jsp.Now I am trying to display it in jsp

```
 <table>
 <c:forEach items="${dnsList}" begin="0" end="${fn:length(dnsList)}"var="dnsList" varStatus="iter">
 <c:forEach items="${connList}" begin="0" end="${fn:length(connList)}"var="connList" varStatus="iter">

 here I am displaying the values
 <tr>
 <td>${dnsList[0]}</td>
 <td>${dnsList[1]}</td>
 <td>${connList[0]}</td>
 <td>${connList[1]}</td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>

</table>
```

My problem is I am getting the same results repeatedly for 2 times.For each url dnstime,connection time records are repeating for multiple times in browser.Please help me.How to iterate over the list.So that I get output in a table as

```
 Required output format is
-------------------------------------------------------------
url1             
------------------------------------------------------
dns_time           connection_time  
dns_update_time    conn_update_time
status_code

url2
-----------------------------------------  
dns_time          connection_time
dns_update_time   conn_update_time
status_code
```

Please anyone can help me??

Answer (score 0):

Make a JSON object and pass the parameters via the response of the servlet. So you'll get the array as such and can easily print it by a simple loop or counter increment.

```
 JSONArray urls=new JSONArray();
 JSONArray time=new JSONArray();
 //Input urls, time and so on ....
 JSONObject dnslist=new JSONObject();
 res.put("urls", urls);
 res.put("time", time);
 PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
 out.println(res.toString());
```

This is in your servlet code.

Now your script code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 something();
});

function something() 
{
   $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    success: function(resp) {
    alert(resp);
    if(resp!=null)
    {
    var response=eval('('+resp+')');
    /*we do this to make resp as an object. O/w we get it as string*/

    urls=response.urls;
    time=response.time;

    }
   }});
}
```

Now urls and time contains both arrays and you can easily print them.
Start using JSON for passing values between sevlets and JSP pages. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

It's better to do complex logic on server side and create special list of objects with required structure. Then you could have simple iteration.

Comment: Is there no alternative solution for this.I want to do in jsp.Please help me.

Comment: JSTL tags and expression language **is** server-side!

Comment: @w4rumy logic should be placed in business layer to make readable jsp/jstl.